# Why does JPA Repository save method automatically update children entities?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin

So I have a bug in my spring boot project which I dont know what to do now. I have following 2 entities:

Customer.kt:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
var projectList: List<Project>?
```

and Project.kt:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="customer_fk")
var customer: Customer?
```

I am using the save method only once in my method, like this:

```
customerRepository.save(existingCustomer)
```

`existingCutomer` has a field `projects`. While debugging, I made sure that `projects` is null. My plan was, just to update the Customer properties without the projects. But still, I use the `save` method only once but he updates my projects also. I dont know why, it doesnt make sense because the `projects`field is empty.

I would like to paste more code here but I hope I pasted the relevant code. Cause the rest is really much and hopefully not important.

Does anybody know if I did something wrong in the given code? Why is the `project` table also updated when `customer` has no projects?

Comment: Because you are using `CascadeType.ALL`

Comment: You can use  _cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE]_ to avoid deleting.

Comment: I have the problem with updating, not deleting. What can I do?

Comment: And still with `CascadeType.ALL`, how does it make sense that `project` gets updated even if it is not inside `customer` anymore?